# Can I ask the following question on this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, arduino

Arduino.Se is closed, and unfortunately for me, I only trust SE users. The last time i asked on this site, my question was stupid or dump or does not belong here, to say the least. I have another question about arduino question which is probably going to be labeled as a shopping question and closed. unfortunately for me, this is the only SE site which accepts arduino questions.

I am not afraid of my question being downvoted or closed, after all i don't have high rep to care about. But out of respect to this community, I learned to ask on meta first whenever i feel that my question isn't fit for the main site, especially that arduino isn't the main subject on this site. So my question is as follows:

---

> I'm doing an arduino uno project and i need to control some motors
>   using my mobile phone through bluetooth. I contacted an arduino
>   reseller in my country and he said that he has bluetooth shield for
>   16$ and bluetooth module for 40$, i don't know which one to buy.
>
> To make things even more confusing, [this guy](http://randomnerdtutorials.com/arduino-control-2-dc-motors-via-bluetooth/) has done something
>   similar to what i wanted to do
>
> using this which is [only around 6$](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093XAV4U)
>
> but i've also seen other projects that are done using the shield, so
>   what to buy? I don't really care about the price, i am willing to pay,
>   but i don't know which one to buy.
>
> At first i thought that arduino bluetooth shield is a shield (cover)
>   that protects the module but [this guy](http://arduinobasics.blogspot.com/2013/01/arduino-basics-bluetooth-tutorial.html) was able to connect arduino
>   using the shield only.
>
> my questions are: what is the difference between the shield and the
>   module? what are the differences between different arduino bluetooth
>   modules? What do you usually buy to connect an android device to
>   arduino using bluetooth?

---

Can I ask this on the main site? it's really not a shopping question because i don't really care about the price, i can buy anything, it's just that, it's so confusing to pick the right one since there are just so many options. I'm willing to take few downvotes, if my question is on topic and if i get good answers, i don't care about my rep, at least not on this site, but I don't want it to be closed.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino

Comment: @Butzke Wait...  Another one?  The 6th?  If this one makes it, that would be great.

Comment: I thought there weren't going to be any more Arduino proposals allowed? I really hope they make it this time...

Comment: Please capitalize "I" when referring to yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks good to me, it is pretty easy to think it is shopping, but it looks like a question about the differences and impact of that.

Comment: Well then, i asked it, fingers crossed :)

Answer (score -6):

Actually it does largely sound like a shopping question, even if you're not asking about price.

Also, when you're outside the Arduino cocoon like here on EE.SE, use grown-up words.  It really pisses me off when people come here asking about "shields" and "sketches".  I know that's what the Arduino documentation uses, but I resent Arduino marketing trying to re-define words for their own purpose at the expense of everyone else.  Besides, "shield" in particular already has a specific meaning in electronics.

I don't care what the voting guidelines are.  If I see "shield" and "sketch" and to some extent "Arduino", I'll look for excuses to downvote and close.  If the question is really about electronics, then it doesn't matter whether an Arduino is involved.  The Arduino questions we get seem to mostly be about user-level issues within the Arduino environment, which don't belong here.

If you can leave the Arduino out of it and ask about the electronics, like how to connect something to a digital output or drive a A/D input, then it is welcome here.  Basically, if it matters that one of the components is an Arduino as opposed to just something with inputs, outputs, power connections, etc, then it shouldn't be here.

I know a lot of people don't agree with this, but like it or not, that's my attitude. Surely there is some appropriate place for Arduino questions out there.

Comment: We know Arduino and even more its lingo is a pet peeve of yours, you've mentioned it several times before. But doesn't every group or community have its own jargon? I bet that at your job you also use terms we don't understand, while your colleagues do.

Comment: @radag: That's exactly the point. "Shield" and "sketch" are private jargon within the arduino playpen only, which is not the domain of this site. I'm not sure we have private jargon at work, but if we do I don't expect others to know it nor that it would acceptable here.  In fact we have to be extra careful using abbreviations and jargon due to the international nature of this site.  What may be obvious and common to someone in the US might make no sense to someone in India, for example, and vice versa.

Comment: Agreed. There is a line many Arduino users straddle between *electronic design* and *electronics assembly*. When it deals with 'shields' as this question does, it appears to be the latter. If you replace Arduino with PC and 'Bluetooth module' with 'Wifi card' I would see no difference and most people would flag the replaced version as a shopping question.

Comment: Having started in electronics long before the Arduino, I agree with Olin that "shield" and "sketch" are some marketing terms to make the platform catchy and approachable, but definitely can confuse people. I try to use quotation marks around these terms so that people know I'm referring to the Arduino terms. They would have been better off calling the "shields" "add-ons" or "plug-ins" or something, but for the life of me I don't know why they'd call a program a "sketch."

Comment: @JYelton See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017875/why-is-an-arduino-program-called-a-sketch

Comment: "I'll look for excuses to downvote and close." ... OMG, I can't believe I just read that. --- I used to be very active on stackoverflow, where questions about multiple different programming languages mixes (Ie.: C++ programming mix with PHP programming), and TAGS are used properly. If you don't understand C++ jargon because you just code ASM, well good for you, then don't read questions tagged C++.